# Terraform use variable based on another value passed during runtime

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-rm

During runtime I want to tell terraform which of those variables are to be used from my .tfvars file I have the following values:

```
website-review-author                  = "test1/fwsfds/34131"
website-dev-publish                 = "test2/fwsfds/34131"
website-other-dispatcher              = "test3/fwsfds/34131"
```

So I want to **data_source_id** to use those variables based on a parameter during runtime:

```
resource "azurerm_managed_disk" "datadisk" {
  name                 = "${var.default_prefix}-${var.environment}-datadisk"
  location             = "${var.default_region}"
  resource_group_name  = "${var.permanent_resources_rg}"
  storage_account_type = "${var.disk_type}"
  create_option        = "Copy"
  source_resource_id   = "${var.website_review_publish.id}" ## I need  to be a dynamic variable. So sometimes it will se website_review_author, other time website-dev-publish
  disk_size_gb         = "${var.data_disk_size_gb}"

  tags = "${var.tags}"

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_storage_account.storage
    #azurerm_managed_disk.osdisk
  ]
}
```

Is it possible in terrraform to switch between variables, so it gets the proper value.
The condition is :

```
 If (var.environment == website-review-author) ## Can be
 website-dev-publish or #website-other-dispathcer 
  then 
 source_resource_id = var.website-review-author #or other value based
 on the parameter
```

I'm new to terraform, so still learning my ways around. I need something like if condition.

Comment: There is a ternary operator which can be handy in situations like this one, but what is the condition that needs to be fulfilled/unfulfilled to switch between the two versions?

Comment: Thanks for the response I will add that in the description. it's basically whether var.environment is   website-dev-publish  then use the variable website-dev-publish   and so on

Comment: @Danny - can you run scripts before? If so, you can setup env variables with IF statement by scripts. i.e. `TF_VAR_PATH_PATTERN=$bamboo_service_path` and the terraform will automatically pick it up and you can use it in terraform files with `${var.PATH_PATTERN}`

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `ternary` operator [1]. If you decide to go down that route, the code would then look like:

```
resource "azurerm_managed_disk" "datadisk" {
  name                 = "${var.default_prefix}-${var.environment}-datadisk"
  location             = "${var.default_region}"
  resource_group_name  = "${var.permanent_resources_rg}"
  storage_account_type = "${var.disk_type}"
  create_option        = "Copy"
  source_resource_id   = var.environment == website-review-author ? var.website-review-author : var.environment == website-dev-publish ? var.website-dev-publish : var.environment == website-other-dispatcher ? var.website-other-dispatcher : null 
  disk_size_gb         = "${var.data_disk_size_gb}"

  tags = "${var.tags}"

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_storage_account.storage
  ]
}
```

It could be made more complex by using other logical operators [2] (e.g., `or`), however if you need all three different values, then I suggest using `workspaces` [3]. For example, in that case you could use the `workspace` name with the ternary operator to decide which value will be assigned:

```
source_resource_id = terraform.workspace == <someworkspacename> ? var.webiste-review-author : var.website-dev-publish
```

EDIT: I added all three conditions. It is really ugly but it should work. I suggest creating a different variable of type `map` and then using it for creating resources. Additionally, whenever the value for environment is changed, the resource will probably be destroyed and recreated, hence why it is better to use `count` or `for_each`.

---

[1] https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/conditionals

[2] https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/operators#arithmetic-and-logical-operators

[3] https://www.terraform.io/cli/workspaces#the-purpose-of-workspaces

Comment: What about the third condition. For author and publish I understand (if that or that) but what about if it's dispatcher?

Comment: Yeah, you could combine it using other logical operators, e.g., `||`. However, it might be better to use the `count` meta-argument and then define three separate blocks. If you don't want that, maybe redefine the variable to be a `map` and then use `for_each`. I'm still not sure I completely understand the use case.

Comment: The use case is : IF source_resource_id = (if envionment == website-review-author    then variable and so I have 3 enviroments so 3 if conditions